# Oracle ADF - CommandImageLink is not working

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

We are developing a web application using Oracle ADF. We have a view object based on query. we drag and dropped this view object as a table in a jsf page(suppose page1). For that table we have added a new column contains a commandImageLink.

From another page we are adding some data to DB using ADF DC, that should be reflected in page1. Actually its not working after that we googled and got solution that if I set CacheResults to false of that table Iterator in Binding layour it will work. I have set to false and reflection is happening.

But my problem is if I set CacheResults to false my commandImageLink is not working. If I set CacheResults to true my commandImageLink is working(navigation is happening).

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:
I would presume that your page1 is part of a bounded task flow. If you are not, you should refactor your code and move the page in a bounded task flow. I would further presume you are using ADF Business Components for your model layer.

Second of all:
Never use CacheResults=false. That solution is a nonsense from ADF perspective.

Now, your problem is re-querying the table info on page opening, therefore:

1. Expose View Object Implementation for your VO. Override executeQuery() method in the newly created java class. Expose this method as client method (this should make the method PUBLIC, visible from Data Controls).
2. drag and drop executeQuery method into your task flow, as method action. Make sure you have this method action as the start activity of your task flow. Furthermore, make sure you are connecting executeQuery() to your page activity in the task flow. This will make sure that every time you open the page, execute query is fired.

Comment: Thanks a lot florinmarcus. It helped me a lot. Thank you.